# How to create a table with left-aligned cells for currency-strings growing from right to left using jspdf-autotable?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I've been trying to modify my table for hours to make it look right, but I just can't find a smart way of doing it.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeYIH.jpg

I want "beløb" and "Restgæld" entries to be left-aligned, but growing from the right ie. looking like this:

```
Beløb
100.000,00 Kr.
     10,00 Kr.
    200,00 Kr.
  1.000,00 Kr.
```

Not:

```
Beløb
   100.000,00 Kr.
        10,00 Kr.
       200,00 Kr.
     1.000,00 Kr.
```

And defintly not

```
Beløb
100.000,00 Kr.
10,00 Kr.
200,00 Kr.
1.000,00 Kr.
```

Also the table must fill the whole width of the page minus margins.

These are my settings:

```
doc.autoTable(columns, data, {
    addPageContent: pageContent,
    margin: { top: 200 },
    columnStyles: {
        Beløb: {
            halign: 'right'
        },
        Restgæld: {
            halign: 'right'
        }
    },
    headerStyles: { fillColor: [131, 149, 160] }
});
```

I've tried setting the column widths manually, but that gave me the same problem. I was thinking of right-aligning the data and manually set the column width to exactly the size of the largest number. My problem with this was that the table became too short then. I think a solution would be to add an empty place-holder column that will span for the rest of the page, but I think this method makes the code too complicated for what it is. Is there a smarter way? Maybe some setting that allows you to set spacings between columns?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set the style `columnWidth: 'wrap';` on the columns you want to fit the content. Currently they are set to the default `auto` which will make them expand if there is space available.

Comment: Yes I've tried that. The problem with wrap is that I get the 2nd scenario.

Comment: Then it is probably a bug. Can you post a bug report in the repo with the some code so that I can reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

use both

`headerStyles: {theme: 'grid',halign: "right"}` and  `columnStyles: {halign: "right"}`